# Does marking a function as inline in C cause all called functions to be implicitly marked as inlined?

Tags: c, inline

In C, if I mark a function as `inline`, and the compiler decides to inline the call, do all function calls from that function also become inlined?

Comment: 1) Definitely not guaranteed, as inline doesn't even guarantee the one you marked as inline is inlined - it is the compiler's call

Comment: @AK4749 The OP seems to understand that, given he wrote "and the compiler decides to inline the call"...

Comment: @ReedCopsey yep, just saw that - it's why your answer is most appropriate. However, from knowing that, he should then know that an implicit inline is not possible - the compiler will make the judgement call in every case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In C, if I mark a function as inline, and the compiler decides to inline the call, do all function calls from that function also become inlined?

Not necessarily.  Inlining a function just inlines that function body (if the compiler "agrees" to do so) - the called functions may be inlined themselves, but may not be, depending on their definition, etc.